# Pass and consume jsessionid to a Java Web Service using PHP as client

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap

I have a Java Web Service which should print out a passed `jsessionid` (stored in JSESSIONID cookie) from a client like this. Later it should be possible to access attributes from this session:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
@WebMethod(operationName = "getContent")
public ArrayList getContent(@WebParam(name = "in") {
   MessageContext mc = context.getMessageContext();
   HttpSession session =  ((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
   System.out.println(session.getId());
}
```

The question is now how to pass a generated `jsessionid` cookie value to this Java Web Service with PHP as client language. The following PHP snippet does not work. The Java Web Service is always generating a new session id:

```
$SOAPClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$SOAPClient->__setCookie("JSESSIONID", "4BFD7FC9C55472BA6BCB1863F266F31C");
$result = $SOAPClient->getContent(array("in" => "all"));
```

Of course I can pass the `jsessionid` value as a Web Service parameter but I want to use the stored attributes from the Java session.

Would be [How can I manually load a Java session using a JSESSIONID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499581/how-can-i-manually-load-a-java-session-using-a-jsessionid) a possible solution to load a session with a passed `jessionid` Web Service parameter to access attributes?