# How to update/remove a role for all principals in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Say I have 3 users logged in to my application, one admin user and 2 normal users who share a set of permissions which are turned into roles, i.e. they each have `ROLE_EDIT`, `ROLE_ADD` and `ROLE_DELETE`, for example.

While logged in, the admin user goes in and removes a role from their shared set of permissions, say the set goes from `ROLE_EDIT, ROLE_ADD, ROLE_DELETE` to just `ROLE_EDIT, ROLE_ADD`. We now want to remove the `ROLE_DELETE` role from the two currently logged in users.

I know `SecurityContextHolder` is thread scoped, so will only have the admin user's information in it. Is there an easy way to access the authentication information for the 2 currently logged in users so that I can remove that role without forcing them to log out and log back in?

Comment: No there isn't, luckily as that would be quite a security risk if that would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SecurityContext` by default will be stored inside the HTTP session under the key `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` (handled by the `SecurityContextHolderFilter` with further delegate to `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`). That means in theory you can first get the `HttpSession` for the user that you need to update his roles , then get his `SecurityContext` from it and do the update.

Sad thing is Servlet does not provide API to get a HTTP session by the session ID , but you can refer to [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1499625/339637) for manually keep track the mapping between the session and the user ID. Or check if the web container provide an API to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question  I understand that you are trying to build a dynamic role model for users without having to log in again. The idea of rewriting roles for all logged in users is not possible because user sessions are unavailable and this unavailability is part of the security and can be bound by the server matching the JSESSIONID during any user request. . That's why you only have admin information in `SecurityContextHolder`. If we understand how the `SecurityContextHolder` became available, we can see that this object is built through the Spring Security Filter Chain bean and the data for this object is taken from the current user session.
For updating users roles we can implement the same Spring Security Filter Chain component(let's call like `RoleRecalculationRequestFilter`), which can be integrated after component which builds `SecurityContextHolder` and then based on info in `SecurityContextHolder` we can load updated roles from any resource(Database, in-memory store and etc.) based on info in `SecurityContextHolder` then set updated list of roles into `SecurityContextHolder` object and that operation will be executed for every request, as result your users always will have up to date roles in context.